# Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values

Tags: react-native

I just started with native react, and wanting to test react-navigation, here is the error I get. Need help please

```
Require cycle: src\HomeScreen\index.js -> src\ChatScreen\index.js -> src\ChatScreen\LucyChat.js -> src\HomeScreen\index.js
```

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.

```
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:67:8 in warn
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:17:23 in warn
- node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:115:8 in metroRequire
* src\ChatScreen\LucyChat.js:4:0 in <unknown>
- node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
* src\ChatScreen\index.js:2:0 in <unknown>
- node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
* src\HomeScreen\index.js:3:0 in <unknown>
- node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
* App.js:3:0 in <unknown>
- node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js:4:0 in <unknown>
- node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:197:45 in guardedLoadModule
* null:null in global codee
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally realized that my mistake was related to circular dependencies.
It's like having three files A, B and C.
A is imported into B,
B is imported into C and
C is imported into A

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue, followed this [answer](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/287#issuecomment-505982647)

```
**package.json**

"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node ./scripts/stfu.js", }

**/scripts/stfu.js**

const fs = require('fs');

const codeToObscure = /console.warn\('Require cycle: '/gi; const problemFilePath = './node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js'; const problemFileContent = fs.readFileSync(problemFilePath, 'utf8'); fs.writeFileSync(   problemFilePath,   problemFileContent.replace(codeToObscure, 'const noConsoleWarn = (""'),   'utf8', );
```

Then do

```
npm install

or

yarn
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I have sold the same problem in react-native navgiation.

What I did ?

Already I was using `react-navigation` like below

```
 export const containerRef = createRef();

 function App(){
   return (
     <NavigationContainer ref={containerRef}>
       ....
     <NavigationContainer>
   );
 }
```

and then I was consuming it like:

```
import {containerRef} from 'filename';

onPress = ()=> containerRef.current.navigate('Chat');
```

**But I updated like below and warning has gone.**

```
 function App(){
   return (
     <NavigationContainer> // removed ref
       ....
     <NavigationContainer>
   );
 }
```

and then I was consuming it like:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

onPress = ()=> useNavigation.navigate('Chat');
```